# prevent < href ="#slider" class="slider-change"> from jumping to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It's been many questions in regards to this but I haven't found a solution that works for me. This is creating a slider , with html and css only

```
<div class="slider-holder">
    <span id="slider-image-1"></span>
    <span id="slider-image-2"></span>
    <span id="slider-image-3"></span>
    <div class="image-holder">
        <img src="1.jpg" class="slider-image" />
        <img src="2.jpg" class="slider-image" />
        <img src="3.jpg" class="slider-image" />
    </div>
    <div class="button-holder">
        <a href="#slider-image-1" class="slider-change"></a>
        <a href="#slider-image-2" class="slider-change"></a>
        <a href="#slider-image-3" class="slider-change"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.slider-holder{
            width: 800px;
            height: 400px;
            background-color: yellow;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-top: 0px;
            text-align: center;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .image-holder
        {
            width: 2400px;
            background-color: red;
            height: 400px;
            clear: both;
            position: relative;

            -webkit-transition: left 2s;
            -moz-transition: left 2s;
            -o-transition: left 2s;
            transition: left 2s;
        }

        .slider-image
        {
            float: left;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            position: relative;
        }

        #slider-image-1:target ~ .image-holder
        {
            left: 0px;
        }

        #slider-image-2:target ~ .image-holder
        {
            left: -800px;
        }

        #slider-image-3:target ~ .image-holder
        {
            left: -1600px;
        }

        .button-holder
        {
            position: relative;
            top: -20px;
        }

        .slider-change
        {
            display: inline-block;
            height: 10px;
            width: 10px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            background-color: brown;
        }
```

The issue is that if I use preventdefault or "#!" the events won't actually happen , and so the slider won't change.

I've also found using

```
function keepLocation(oldOffset) {
  if (window.pageYOffset!= null){
    st=oldOffset;
  }
  if (document.body.scrollWidth!= null){
    st=oldOffset;
  }
  setTimeout('window.scrollTo(0,st)',10);
}
```

and adding

```
<a href="#slider-image-1" onclick="keepLocation(window.pageYOffset);" class="slider-change"></a>
            <a href="#slider-image-2" onclick="keepLocation(window.pageYOffset);" class="slider-change"></a>
            <a href="#slider-image-3" onclick="keepLocation(window.pageYOffset);" class="slider-change"></a>
```

works but there's that split second up and back down , which doesn't look good.

Anyone with a possible solution for the link to work with any jumping or moving of the page ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: try e.stopPropagation() it might help you.

Comment: What do you use to trigger the slider change?

Comment: To trigger the slider change is  <a href="#slider-image-1" class="slider-change"></a>...2..3 and clicking goes to top

Answer (score 0):

Just use e.preventDevault() in function

```
function keepLocation(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: This won't work because then the link won't work in the address bar , it prevents the whole thing all together , including loading the link , and it's essential to make the slider work